# fix translation in CSS 3d Cube rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to CSS transform 3d working on a 3d cube carousel. I want the cube to rotate within a fixed div but somehow it is translating along x axis a bit as well.

```
.back, .carousel__slide:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateZ(-7.5em) rotateY(180deg);
}

.right, .carousel__slide:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(7.5em);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.left, .carousel__slide:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-7.5em);
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.front, .carousel__slide:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateZ(7.5em);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j2un66dt/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix the problem by setting :

```
.carousel__slide {
     width: 100%;
}
```

if you want to keep the width at `302px;`simply set it to `100%` and put `.carousel__slide`inside a new div with a width of `302px;`and no padding.

Comment: the problem I mentioned is with the abrupt translation along x axis, not about the width.

Comment: making it 100% will prevent it from translating among the x axis, try it and see